# While and Array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

```
     <?php    
     public function fetchAll($sql){
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
       $out=array();
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $out[] = $row;
       }
       return $out;
     }
```

1. Here array() has no initial size. can u tell me how this works without any size
   2.in while statement we are saving arrays in a non declared variable, without any size too.how this statement works. how long this loop will work.

Comment: Where is the mysqli_query in that function? What is $sql coming from? More info please.

Comment: As it stands, it won't work.... you input $sql but don't do anything with it, yet suddenly have a $result which mysteriously appears from nowhere

Comment: sizeof($result);// will gives the loop size

Comment: U use $sql but never used in your function...

Comment: mysqli_query is a built in function in php. $sql is the query by user for fetching from database
*** and this is the part of code of a running project. i just dont understand this part

Comment: sorry... i have corected the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
$out=array();
```

only initializes the $out-variable as an array, that is initially empty.

```
$out[]=$row;
```

will ADD an item/element into the array, increasing it's size by one on each cycle of the loop. Loop will run as many times as there are rows in your sql-result. Please read [array_push documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to fully understand this shorthand.